# Cant get value from ajax request to be save in variable outside the success

Tags: javascript, ajax

Once again I've been beating my head against the wall, trying to pull this part of returned data from ajax to a variable outside the function.

When I return the value it always comes up `undefined` when I `alert()` inside it shows the proper values.

```
function getItemInfo(itemHashPass) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php//Welcome/getItem', //This is the current doc
        type: "POST",       
        data: 'iHash='+itemHashPass,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data){

          return data.Response.data.inventoryItem.itemName;

        }
    });  

}
```

I've also tried

```
function getItemInfo(itemHashPass) {
  var tmp = null;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php//Welcome/getItem', //This is the current doc
    type: "POST",       
    data: 'iHash='+itemHashPass,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){

      tmp = data.Response.data.inventoryItem.itemName;

    }
 });  
 return tmp;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be `return`ing from the `success` callback. Just do your business in the call back.

Comment: I just added an edit to another way i've tried

Comment: No. you have to *do* stuff. Not just assign variables. So, what were you going to *do* with the `itemName`? Whatever it is, do it *inside* the callback.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about it all wrong. I was way over complicating it, and I really didnt have to. I appreciate you guys taking the time to try and get through my thick skull !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jonathan said you should write your business logic in the callback or you can try Deferred syntax. In this case it will looks like

```
   function yourBusinnesLogicFunction() {
       ...
       getItemInfo("password_hash_value").done(
          function(data){
              alert(data.Response.data.inventoryItem.itemName);
          }
       )
    }

    function getItemInfo(itemHashPass) {
      var tmp = null;
      return $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php//Welcome/getItem', //This is the current doc
        type: "POST",       
        data: 'iHash='+itemHashPass,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
       })
     }
```